# Write $\frac{2}{1+x}$ as an infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The question on the test was to write $\frac{2}{1+x}$ as an infinite geometric series (IGS).

My thought is that the sum of an IGS is $S = \dfrac{a_1}{1-r}$ .  So, I viewed $a_1$ as = 2 and $r = (-x)$.
Writing this in the form of an IGS:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {2\cdot{(-x)}^{i-1}}$$

Am I on the correct path here?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

Your are correct.